# Visual Studio across two drives, one drive failed

Tags: hard-drive, installation, visual-studio, reinstall, visual-studio-2013

Recently my D: drive hard disk failed, Visual Studio 2013 update 4 was installed there, but of course VS also took 10+ GB off the C drive where the OS (Windows 8.1) is for its installation, basically VS was installed across two drives.

And now that my D drive failed I cannot repair, modify or uninstall visual studio, each of these option returns multiple different errors.

I'd like to either reinstall VS to have it on my C drive completely, or wait until my data is salvaged. I'd rather wait but the reality of the situation is that I probably cannot.

What do you suggest I do out of the two options?

Do you think that when my data is salvaged VS would proceed to work normally?

If I do reinstall on C drive once my D drive data is back, would there be any complications or would I just be able to delete the VS installation folder there?

When I run the uninstall option it gives me the following errors:

> Visual Studio core features Fatal error during installation.
>   Windows phone emulator 8.0 configurator Package failed.
>   Team explorer for Microsoft visual studio 2013 package failed
>   Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 performance collection tools ENU package failed
>   Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 performance collection tools package failed
>   Blend for Visual Studio 2013 ENU resources package failed
>   Blend for Visual Studio 2013 package failed

Also here's the log file: http://pastebin.com/pw8q5n4g

Edit: the uninstall has been successful due to IObit uninstaller but the reinstall is unsuccessful.
I cannot change installation path even after messing with the registry (d drive doesn't exist no more), and if I do trick the system into installing to C drive (subst d: c:path), I'm getting further errors:

> Microsoft office 2013 developer tools for microsoft visual studio (x64) package failed 
>   Microsoft office 2013 developer tools for microsoft visual studio (x64) ENU language pack package failed

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24423/discussion-on-question-by-dood-visual-studio-across-two-drives-one-drive-failed).

Answer (score 0):

The unfortunate truth is that once the regular (official!) uninstaller has failed, you're SOL. I once spent a day trying to manually remove Visual Studio 2013 from the registry. No luck, of course, so I had to reinstall Windows.

Originally, I had moved the folder to my new SSD and created a symlink. This link was then somehow (probably an update) removed. Everything went to hell after that.

Visual Studio consists of tens of thousands of tiny components. It's impossible to manage manually. Third-party cleaners are extremely unlikely to work.